# Preventing artifacts when shrinking a popover's content size

Tags: ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

I have a navigation controller inside a popover in an iPad app.  The navigation controller holds a hierarchy of list views. They all can have differing numbers of rows.

When I navigate from one to the next, and back, I change the content size using `setContentSizeForViewInPopover:` to the correct table height. This works, and looks good when the popover needs to grow to fit the view.

BUT when the new size is smaller than the current popover size, the system seems to start the size animation by "blacking out" (clipping) the portion of the view that is about to be truncated, which is an ugly visual artifact.  Ideally, I'd like the extra portion of the view to remain visible and just be progressively covered up by the animation.

Anyone know a way around this or better way I should be thinking of it?

Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, sorry to hear you have issues with UIPopoverController as well. I decided to write my own instead of dealing with this junk. Good luck!

Comment: The popover actually works very well. The problem is poor documentation. Writing own component for every component which is badly documented doesn't seem like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure I understand your problem.

The problem is not in the popover, it is in the view inside the popover.
If you are adjusting popover size, I suppose it's because you have changed the size of the view it contains. Did you change popover contents size with an animation? If not, what you see is exactly what you have programmed.

The view in your popover should be always autoresizible to fill the popover entirely.